# Force Jekyll to stop building using tags?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, exit

Is it possible to forcefully stop Jekyll from building the site using tags, if certain condition is unset? Say, if I want to make sure some variable is set properly before Jekyll can build the site, I'd hope to use something like:

```
{% unless site.setting.size > 0 %}
  {% error ......... %}
{% endunless %}
```

Is such maneuver possible, or some sort of alternative method already exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hook plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/).

Here is an example for a file that can be named **_plugins/hook_site_after_init.rb**.

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :after_init do |site|
  puts "Firing site, after_init from #{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"
  if site.config["source"] != "yolo"
    raise "Please check 'source' variable in configuration. Currently set to " + site.config["source"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm out of luck for using external plugin. It's my fault to forget mentioning those templates are for Github Pages, which disallows external plugin usage.